# WCF service WebInvoke attribute and support some behaviors

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

Hello currently I have legacy WCF service under FW3.5. that using some SilverLigt application,
I need to extend this WCF service for support JSON format and call it for JavaScript application,
currently service look like

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Alcatraz
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(SomeError))]
    public SomeClass DoSomething(SomeClass data)
    {
    }
}
```

As I know for support JSON format for WCF service I need add WebInvoke attribute to methods

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "players")]
```

add `[DataContract]` attribure to *SomeClass* class. But I am not sure that if I will add this all application will work in the same way ?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="silverlightFaults" type="myNS.WCF.SilverlightFaultBehavior, SilverlightFaultBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="binaryHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" closeTimeout="00:02:00">
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="655360" maxBufferSize="655360"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SilverlightFaultBehavior">
        <silverlightFaults/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myNS.WCF.MyServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="myNS.WCF.MyServiceBehavior" name="myNS.WCF.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binaryHttpBinding" contract="myNS.WCF.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightFaultBehavior"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What I need to do for make compatibility with other clients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [WebGet] / [WebInvoke] attributes, you need to use an endpoint with the `webHttpBinding` and with a behavior using the `<webHttp/>` endpoint behavior - see edits to your config below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="silverlightFaults" 
           type="myNS.WCF.SilverlightFaultBehavior, SilverlightFaultBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="binaryHttpBinding" 
               allowCookies="true" 
               receiveTimeout="00:02:00" 
               sendTimeout="00:02:00" 
               openTimeout="00:02:00" 
               closeTimeout="00:02:00">
        <binaryMessageEncoding/>
        <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="655360" maxBufferSize="655360"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SilverlightFaultBehavior">
        <silverlightFaults/>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="Web">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myNS.WCF.MyServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="myNS.WCF.MyServiceBehavior" name="myNS.WCF.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="customBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="binaryHttpBinding" 
                contract="myNS.WCF.MyService" 
                behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightFaultBehavior"/>
      <endpoint address="web" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="myNS.WCF.MyService" 
                behaviorConfiguration="Web"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```